# Problem set to accompany "A Course in Arithmetic"

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, quadratic-forms, modular-forms

The classic "A Course in Arithmetic" by Serre comes without exercises.

This is a little let down, and I would like to ask, if there are suitable problem sets, which can be used to accompany the study of this text.

The textbook is based on lectures Serre gave, so I wonder if the original problem sets can be found?

Comment: Did Serre give problems during his lectures? Otherwise what are "the original problem sets"?

Comment: Well, I do not know. Thats why I ask.

Comment: A long time ago I skimmed some parts of the book, but have forgotten what it covers. Maybe if you describe its contents here someone could advise you what already published books have good problems relevant to that content.

Comment: The book can be found online. In the first half of the book p-adic numbers and quadratic forms are introduced. The Hasse-Minkowski-Theorem is proven. The second half gives an introduction to modular forms. At the moment i am mainly interested in the first half of the book.